# How do I write a smart makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm new to linux and new to makefiles so I'm a little stumped at this point. I've been staring the make manual for an hour now and figured I would just ask:

I want to create a makefile for a relatively small project, whose source files are in `proj/src/`, and within subdirectories of that location. I have written a makefile at `proj/makefile` and want to use it to gather up all the source files, find their dependencies, and compile the result into `proj/build/`. Here is what I've written:

```
# here are my files and directories (there are also header files that are not
# listed here, but these are referred to from within the .cpp files with
# respect to the proj/src directory)
# proj/makefile
# proj/src/
# proj/src/main.cpp
# proj/src/dir1/
# proj/src/dir1/source1.cpp
# proj/src/dir2/
# proj/src/dir2/source2.cpp
# proj/build/

srcDir = src/
buildDir = build/

# This is a list of all the object files (can I get this programatically?)
objects = main.o source1.o source2.o

all: prog

# Here I want to compile all source (.cpp) files from src/ and all of its subdirectories, and to find the dependencies I want to call g++ -MM to automatically generate the list:
%.o: %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MM -I $(srcDir)

clean:
                rm -rf *o $(buildDir)/prog
```

This is far from functional but I wanted to give it ago before asking. Running this gives

> make: *** No rule to make target `main.o', needed by`prog'.  Stop.

So presumably my attempt at automatically writing the object files failed. If someone could give me some direction that would be great, I'm hoping that between the comments and code you can make out the intention.

**EDIT: I have now tried the following:**

```
SHELL := /bin/bash                                                              
srcDir = src                                                                    
buildDir = bin                                                                  
sources := $(shell find $(srcDir) -name *.cpp)                                  
objects := $(sources:%.cpp=%.o)                                                 

-include $(sources:%.cpp=%.d)                                                   

# This is a list of all the object files (can I get this programatically?)      
all: prog                                                                       

prog:   $(objects)                                                              
    g++ $(objects) -o $(buildDir)/prog                                          

# Here I want to compile all source (.cpp) files from src/ and all of its subdirectories, and to find the dependencies I want to call g++ -MM to automatically generate the list:
%.o: %.cpp                                                                      
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MMD -MP -c -I $(srcDir)                                    

clean:                                                                          
    rm -rf *o $(buildDir)/hello
```

But when I run this I get the following error:

```
g++  -MMD -MP -I src
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/core/Cell.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Be careful with `rm -rf`

Comment: Check out http://github.com/cdesjardins/makefiles for a simple makefile framework.

Comment: where is the .cpp file for main.o? if its src/main.cpp the target must be src/main.o ... have a look at makefile functions like wildcards etc.

Comment: %.o: %.cpp      do you have the corresponding .cpp for all the objects you want to make?

Answer (score 2):

It wants to build `main.o` from `main.cpp`, but there is no `main.cpp` at the top level. You could specify the full paths of the object files, if they are to be built alongside the source files:

```
objects = $(srcDir)/main.o $(srcDir)/dir1/source1.o $(srcDir)/dir2/source2.o
```

> can I get this programatically?

I do it using gnumake's `shell` function:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
sources := $(shell find $(srcDir) -name *.cpp)
objects := $(sources:%.cpp=%.o)
```

> to find the dependencies I want to call g++ -MM to automatically generate the list

Use `-MMD` to generate dependency files as well as compiling. It's also a good idea to specify `-MP` here - that makes sure the dependencies are correctly updated when you remove a header. Given the variables defined above, you can include the dependency files with

```
-include $(sources:%.cpp=%.d)
```

Comment: How would I generate these dependency files? Would I call `$(CXX) -MMD` for every file? How would this look?

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz: Just replace `-MM` with `-MMD -MP` in the build rule you already have. The dependency files will be regenerated every time the associated object is built.

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz: Also, add `-c`, so that it compiles the object but doesn't try to link it on its own.

Comment: Mike, I tried implementing your suggestion, but am obviously doing it wrong. I have appended my new makefile to the OP; please let me know what I might be doing it wrong (I think the *recipe* part of my code isn't telling `g++` what to compile, but I don't know how to do that).

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz: Add `$<` to specify the rule's first prerequisite (i.e. the source file) as the input; and `-o $@` to specify the rule's target (i.e. the object file) as the output. These, and other, automatic variables are documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).